# Getting constrained layout to work with nested subplots in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to create nested subplots in Matplotlib, where each plot is produced by a function that takes an `axis` object as an argument. Some of the plot functions can create subplots of their own.

This simple example works:

```py
def myplot(ax):
    gs = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(2, 1, subplot_spec=ax)
    fig = ax.figure
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 0])
    ax1.plot([1, 3, 2])
    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 0])
    ax2.plot([1, 3, 2])

f, a = plt.subplot_mosaic("ab") 
myplot(a['a'])
```

However, with complex figures, the label ticks and legends overlap.

[image: nested subplots]

Constrained layouts is typically the way to go, but adding that throws an error.

```py
def myplot(ax):
    gs = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(2, 1, subplot_spec=ax)
    fig = ax.figure
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 0])
    ax1.plot([1, 3, 2])
    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 0])
    ax2.plot([1, 3, 2])

f, a = plt.subplot_mosaic("ab")
f.set_constrained_layout(True)
myplot(a['a'])
```

```
AttributeError: 'Axes' object has no attribute 'rowspan'
```

How can I fix this code?

Comment: That seems to be a bug, which you could report to Matplotlib.  OTOH, constrained_layout won't work as it is trying to make the axes non-overlapping, and you have specifically made the axes overlap.

Comment: Ooops, no, the issue is that `ax` is not a subplot spec.  Still arguably a bug, but you should be doing `subplot_spec=ax.get_subplotspec()`.

Comment: Thank you @JodyKlymak! Using `subplot_spec=ax.get_subplotspec())` solves the problem!! <3